# how to download a file in a site from command  line writing it in php

Tags: php, command-line, download, opensuse

when I use wget for dowloading it is successful but it will not work with `exec_shell()`
or `system`
then I tried to use curl
here is the code for downloading a site that Joe in another question told me from [this site](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm)

```
function curl_download($Url){

// is cURL installed yet?
if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
    die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
}

// OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
$ch = curl_init();

// Now set some options (most are optional)

// Set URL to download
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);

// Set a referer
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.org/yay.htm");

// User agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");

// Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Timeout in seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

// Download the given URL, and return output
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
curl_close($ch);

return $output;
}
```

it is working for downloading a page but I want to change it to download from command line 
if you have better suggestions please tell me

for example I used this:

```
<?php
  $output=exec_shell('wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/wget/wget-latest.tar.gz');
?>
```

it is not working when I echoed it

but when I enter this in command line it will download it on /root:

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/wget/wget-latest.tar.gz
```

Comment: Both `wget` and `curl` work perfectly from the commandline. You might need to configure the commandline that is used by `shell_exec` and `system` with your PHP setup to make it work with *that* commandline as well. But that's merely system configuration and has nothing to do with the PHP code you've put into your question.

Comment: So... are you asking how to use the `curl` command line tool instead of PHP then?

Comment: No I know how to download from commandline I don't know how to execute it right in PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can pass any parameters to your script from command line interface. But you have to enable such functionality in php if not (just try `php -i` in command line).

To use parameters in php script you should use `$argv` array. For example:

`php yourscript.php http://myurl.com`

```
$url = $argv[1]; //it will contain first parameter passed to your script
curl_download($url);
```

Check out [official manual at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

Comment: Actually you want `$argv[1]` because `$argv[0]` is always the name of the script itself.